# Create a heightmap from gps coordinates

Tags: c#, android, gps, terrain

I am currently working on a project which I want to integrate the creation of 3d terrain based on gps coordinates.  Right now the the rendering algorithm uses, a heightmap, I am stucked at creating that heightmap from gps coordinates, Basically, I am interesenting in translating from gps coordinates to cartesian coordinates that fit inside my heightmap.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the other way around:

[3D coordinates on a sphere to Latitude and Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674149/3d-coordinates-on-a-sphere-to-latitude-and-longitude)

But all the logic / math is there. Basically GPS coordinates are represented in longitude and latitude coordinates, which are spherical coordinates in radians.

I'm not sure how height is represented in GPS coordinates however.