# XYZ Sphere Coordinates to XY Bird's Eye View

Tags: math, image-processing, geometry

I have XYZ coordinates the represent pixels located on a sphere. I haven't had much luck finding a solution, but how would I translate each XYZ coordinate to represent a Bird's eye view on a XY plain.

I checked out all the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674149/3d-coordinates-on-a-sphere-to-latitude-and-longitude) but nothing worked.

Comment: Convert the XYZ to lattitude/longitude/altitude, and then use a [map projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) to project the point onto a flat surface. Which one you use is up to you; but you're bound to get some distortion in any case, since you can't flatten a sphere without stretching some parts of it more than others.

Comment: I may be missing something, but you're already talking cartesian coordinates XYZ, not spherical r-phi-theta, so the projection of (X1,Y1,Z1) onto the XY plane would just be (X1,Y1).

Comment: Yea you're right, but plotting X1,Y1 result in a circular sphere flat shape. I'm looking to translate the XYZ to a bird's eye view.